# Getting multiple different ratings for different items to work

Tags: html, jquery, angularjs

So I've been trying to get a star rating for multiple items to work, but with how my code is, I think they're using each other's ratings for themselves.

HTML:

```
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470315232801-e91a8bb8adb6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1248&q=80" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Buck Moon</h3>
                        <p>Alan Emory</p>
                        <p>32 upvotes</p>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1">
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked" onmouseover="starmark(this)" onclick="" starmark(this) id="1three" style="font-size:40px;cursor:pointer"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked" onmouseover="starmark(this)" onclick="" starmark(this) id="2three" style="font-size:40px;cursor:pointer"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked" onmouseover="starmark(this)" onclick="" starmark(this) id="3three" style="font-size:40px;cursor:pointer"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked" onmouseover="starmark(this)" onclick="" starmark(this) id="4three" style="font-size:40px;cursor:pointer"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked" onmouseover="starmark(this)" onclick="" starmark(this) id="5three" style="font-size:40px;cursor:pointer"></span>
                                <br />
                                <button class="btn2 btn-default" onclick="showrating()"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I've set the button to be a submit for the rating, but not sure why it keeps the other instances of the star rating.

How do I fix this using a separate file or whatever I need to do to make them apply to different buttons? Also, I've tried renaming the ratings and it still keeps those in the buttons.

Comment: `onclick="" starmark(this)` doesn't really seem a working code. Could you also please share your JS?

Comment: I didn't have a JS file for it. I was wondering how to do it in JS. I apologize for the miswording of my issue. Using the submit button after hovering the star rating is how it works currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
function starmark(el) {
  $(".fa-star").removeClass("active");
  $(el).addClass("active");
}

function showrating() {
  let rating = $(".fa-star.active").attr("id").charAt(0);
  console.log(rating);
}
```

```css
.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-1">
        <span class="fa fa-star checked" onmouseover="starmark(this)" onclick="starmark(this)"  id="1three" style="font-size:40px;cursor:pointer">1</span>
        <span class="fa fa-star checked" onmouseover="starmark(this)" onclick="starmark(this)"  id="2three" style="font-size:40px;cursor:pointer">2</span>
        <span class="fa fa-star checked" onmouseover="starmark(this)" onclick="starmark(this)"  id="3three" style="font-size:40px;cursor:pointer">3</span>
        <span class="fa fa-star checked" onmouseover="starmark(this)" onclick="starmark(this)"  id="4three" style="font-size:40px;cursor:pointer">4</span>
        <span class="fa fa-star checked" onmouseover="starmark(this)" onclick="starmark(this)"  id="5three" style="font-size:40px;cursor:pointer">5</span>
        <br />
        <button class="btn2 btn-default" onclick="showrating()">ShowRating</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume the first is a js file, the second is a CSS file and the third is the main HTML file, correct?

Comment: @bingo9499 That's correct, though all of it could be in the main HTML file using <style> and <script> tags.

Comment: Alright. Only separated it out to make sure my main isn't too flooded.

Comment: @bingo9499 Glad if I was able to help you. In case this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer to resolve your question as solved/answered.

Comment: Only issue I'm having now is that there's no alert showing from the button. However, that's a different issue.

Comment: @bingo9499 If you want to show an alert on button click, then just replace console.log(rating); in the function showRating() with alert(rating).